# How to implement equals/hashcode in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, equals

I stack with with my searching about equals/hashcode in kotlin

I understand what equals and (==) work fine with data classes but with regular class, i suppose, we should override equals and hashcode methods:

```
class GroupWithData {

    var group: Group? = null

    var data: List<Data>? = null


    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as GroupWithData

        if (group!= other.group) return false
        if (data!= other.data) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = group?.hashCode() ?: 0
        result = 31 * result + (data?.hashCode() ?: 0)
        return result
    }
```

But when i try to equal two List it doesn't work right.

PS: Group and Data classes are "data class"

Comment: Would you consider two `GroupWithData`s equal if they had `List`s of different types (e.g. an `ArrayList` and a `LinkedList`) but holding the same elements in the same order?

Comment: Yes i consider that this Lists would be equals

Comment: Hmmm, the usual implementation of `equals()` for `List`s should do what you want.  (Assuming you don't have some strange implementation which breaks it…)  `Data` is definitely a `data class`?  What property types does it have?  (If any are not primitives or strings, could _those_ be comparing as unequal?)

Comment: I want to note that in the debug every element of the list 1 (List<GroupsWithData>)  is equal to list 2 (List<GroupsWithData>) if iterated over them
but for some reason the lists themselves are not, and now this is the most incomprehensible thing for me

Somehow can it be because i retrieve data from Room Database?

Comment: What are the actual list classes?  (`List` is an interface, so it'll need to be some class which implements that.  It _should_ implement `equals()` to compare the contents — or, more likely, inherit from e.g. `AbstractList` which does.  But if it doesn't, that would explain your issue.)

Comment: it is an ArrayList

Comment: Both of the objects you're comparing are actual `java.util.ArrayList`s?  (And not subclasses of that?)  If so, then their contents must compare differently somehow.  You could check by writing out a comparison manually (e.g. `data.zip(other.data).filter{ it.first != it.second }.forEach{ println(it) }`).

Comment: they are both ArrayLists but from kotlin collections

Comment: Need to see the data class to know what's going on. Note that data classes properties are supposed to be immutable, I believe the data classes default override methods assume this. For similar reasons a data class shouldn't have an object reference that can be mutated as a property.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Inspect the contents of `data class Data`: does it override `equals`? does any of the members of `Data` class is of a non-primitive type and overrides `equals`? For more explanation and examples read further.

### How to implement equals/hashcode in kotlin?

You are absolutely right, with regular classes we must override `equals` and `hashCode` functions **if we want to** compare two objects by the value and not the reference. Implementation of `equals` may be anything you like. It totally depends on the business logic of your application and what is deemed "equal" in your particular case.

The implementation you have is actually good enough to start with. Basically checking identity (aka as comparison by reference, `===` Kotlin operator), checking if `other` is of the same instance class and anything further is up to business logic.

Implementation of `hashCode` function may use the same members that you have compared in the `equals` function, but it is just as fine to use other members of a class.

*Note: it is generally considered good practice do override both functions `equals` and `hashCode`. Even if `hashCode` is not used directly in your code it can be used under some implementations of libraries you could use. **If two objects are equal their hash code must be equal too**. Hash code must stay the same if the object did not change.*

### Why two lists may not be equal?

I'm not exactly sure but it maybe that the problem is in the `Data` data class or in the values of it's members.

I ran two simple tests with primitive type and `data class Data` that looked like this:

Test #1

```
    var list1: List<Int> = listOf(1,2,3,4)
    var list2: List<Int> = arrayListOf(1,2,3,4)
    var list3: List<Int> = LinkedList<Int>().also { it.addAll(listOf(1,2,3,4)) }

    fun equals(): Boolean {
        return list1 == list3 && list1 == list2 && list2 == list3
    }

    println(equals())
```

Test #2

```
    data class Data(var i: Int = 0)
    var list1: List<Data> = listOf(Data(1),Data(2),Data(3),Data(4))
    var list2: List<Data> = arrayListOf(Data(1),Data(2),Data(3),Data(4))
    var list3: List<Data> = LinkedList<Data>().also { it.addAll(listOf(Data(1),Data(2),Data(3),Data(4))) }

    fun equals(): Boolean {
        return list1 == list3 && list1 == list2 && list2 == list3
    }

    println(equals())
```

And the print was `true` in both cases. It is true because following Kotlin documentation it says:

> Two lists are considered equal if they have the same sizes and structurally equal elements at the same positions.

[Documentation reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections-overview.html#list).

Structural equality is described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality).

Now, here is the altered `Data` class and there is something weird happening in it's implementation of `equals`:

```
    data class Data(var i: Int = 0) {
        // Custom equals!
        override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            if (this === other) return true
            if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

            other as Data

            return (i + other.i) % 2 == 1
        }
    }
```

If you try to compare the same lists with the `Data` objects added in the same order the lists will not be equal because the comparison of two `Data` objects sometimes returns `false`.

If `Data` class contains another non-primitive type and it's `equals` method doesn't return `true` for actually equal objects this could also be the problem. So on and so forth.